# Search path for TCL script execution

Tags: tcl

Is there a variable holding the search path where 'source' command looks for TCL files? If so, is there a way to edit it?

Comment: If you want to source files from the same dir as the currently sourced file, use this: `source [file join [file dirname [info script]] otherfile.tcl]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the **source** command needs a path, either absolute or relative, to the file to be loaded.  It's only when you get to **package require** that things like the **auto_path** variable come into effect.

Comment: The `auto_path` also comes into effect if you've set things up for autoloading, but that's not recommended way of loading code these days as the effects are often rather more surprising than you'd really want. Explicit loading reduces the number of bugs.